# jQuery function that auto-advances to next input field doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to auto-advance to the next input field within a class once the input's max length is reached, but the code snippets I've found don't work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="input_row d-flex justify-content-center" id="first_word">
    <div class="empty_status" id="input_01" onclick="setClass(this)">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
    </div>
    <div class="empty_status" id="input_02" onclick="setClass(this)">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
    </div>
    <div class="empty_status" id="input_03" onclick="setClass(this)">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
    </div>
    <div class="empty_status" id="input_04" onclick="setClass(this)">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
    </div>
    <div class="empty_status" id="input_05" onclick="setClass(this)">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return /[a-z]/i.test(event.key)">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery code I used:

```
$(".inputs").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
    }
});
```

Nothing happens though. I added an alert to the function as well, but the alert was never called.

After Googling around, I found this sample of code on the jQuery API, which I thought might be useful to check and see if the keyup event handler was being called.

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keyup() called." );
});
```

I added an `id="target"` to my first input field and then tried it, but it didn't work either at first. However, rewriting it as a named function, and then adding an inline `onkeyup` event to the input in the HTML to call it by name actually DID work.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong? I might be able to figure out a way to make the original function work that way, but I've already got enough going inline that I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to throw this out there, in case anyone runs into the same problem.

My code didn't work for two reasons:

Since the inputs lived in different divs, next wouldn't work. Changing the code to

```
    $(".inputs").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
          $(this).closest('div').next().children().focus();
        }
    });
```

worked just fine.

It also didn't work because in my HTML document, I was calling the script src in the head of my document, instead of at the bottom. Apparently, you can run into problems if the script loads before the html elements they're handling do. I didn't know that, I've only been working on original code for less than a month.

Thanks to u/virtual_lee123 on reddit for helping me figure it out.

Comment: One little thing, you SHOULD put the script tag in the head but add a defer attribute to it. This is recommanded because the script can be downloaded while your HTML is parsed giving you better load times.

It is executed once the page has finished parsing.

<script src="..." defer></script>

Alternatively you can use the load event of the page or in jQuery the $(document).ready() event handler.